# Running xjc from java code

Tags: java, jaxb, operating-system, xjc

I am using xjc to generate classes from xsd. The generation has to happen inside the java code. Right now I have done it like this:

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting...");
            child.waitFor();
            System.out.println("waiting ended..");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

The output for the above program is:

```
waiting...
```

I have to use the classes after they are generated. The problem here is that the subprocess never exits and the control is never back to the java program!
Is there a way to do this without `getRuntime().exec()` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually use the driver class (*com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver*) behind the command line tool. This worked for me:

```
import com.sun.tools.xjc.BadCommandLineException;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver;
import com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCListener;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Generator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws BadCommandLineException, IOException {
        final String targetDir = "jaxb-files";
        Path path = Paths.get(targetDir);
        if(!Files.exists(path)) {
            Files.createDirectories(path);
        }
        Driver.run(new String[]{"-d", targetDir,
                "D:\\dev\\onepoint\\tui\\java\\xsdjsonschema\\src\\main\\xsd\\test.xsd"}, new XJCListener() {

            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException e) {
                printError(e, "ERROR");
            }

            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) {
                printError(e, "FATAL");
            }

            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException e) {
                printError(e, "WARN");
            }

            @Override
            public void info(SAXParseException e) {
                printError(e, "INFO");
            }

            private void printError(SAXParseException e, String level) {
                System.err.printf("%s: SAX Parse exception", level);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                new InputStreamReader(child.getInputStream()));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
            }
```

Comment: I have tried  this also.. The problem is that it never exits from this also!! That is because the process never ends!